# R; Populating a matrix with a for loop iterating over a vector

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, iteration

I am not very experienced with R, and have been struggling for days to repeat a string of code to fill a data matrix. My instinct is to create a for loop.

I am a biology student working on colour differences between sets of images, making use of the R package colordistance. The relevant data has been loaded in R as a list of 8x4 matrices (each matrix describes the colours in one image). Five images make up one set and there are 100 sets in total. Each set is identified by a number (not 1-100, it's an interrupted sequence, but I have stored the sequence of numbers in a vector called 'numberlist'). I have written the code to extract the desired data in the right format for the first set, and it is as follows;

```
## extract the list of matrices belonging to the first set (A3) from the the full list
A3<-histlist[grep('^3',names(histlist))] 
## create a colour distance matrix (cdm), ie a pairwise comparison of "similarity" between the five matrices stored in A3
cdm3<-colordistance::getColorDistanceMatrix(A3, method="emd", plotting=FALSE)
## convert to data frame to fix row names
cdm3df<-as.data.frame(cdm3) 
## remove column names
names(cdm3df)<-NULL 
## return elements in the first row and column 2-5 only (retains row names).
cdm3filtered<-cdm3df[1,2:5]
```

Now I want to replace "3" in the code above with each number in 'numberlist' (not sure whether they should be as.factor or as.numeric). I've had many attempts starting with `for (i in numberlist) {...}` but with no successful output. To me it makes sense to store the output from the loop in a storage matrix; `matrix(nrow=100,ncol=4)` but I am very much stuck, and unable to populate my storage matrix row by row by iterating the code above...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### Updates

What I want the outputs of the loop to to look like (+ appended in the storage matrix);

```
> cdm17filtered                                
17clr 0.09246918 0.1176651 0.1220622 0.1323586
```

This is my attempt:

```
for (i in numberlist$X) {
  A[i] <- histlist[grep(paste0('^',i),names(histlist))]
  cdm[i] <- colordistance::getColorDistanceMatrix(A[i], method="emd", plotting=FALSE)
  cdm[i]df <- as.data.frame(cdm[i])
  cdm[i]filtered <- cdm[i]df[1,2:5]
  print(A[i]) # *insert in n'th column of storage matrix
}
```

The above is not working, and I'm missing the last bit needed to store the outputs of the loop in the storage matrix. (I was advised against using rbind to populate the storage matrix because it is slow..)

Comment: Have you tried a for loop, with `grep(paste0('^',i)...`

Comment: @anotherfred. Thanks, the paste0() function could be useful. However
`for(i in numberlist){
  A[i]<-histlist[grep(paste0('^',i),names(histlist))]
  print(A[i])
}` 
only returns one, not all five matrices for each i. Conversely, `histlist[grep('^3',names(histlist))]` works correctly, and returns all 5 matrices belonging to i=3.

Comment: Really? What is in `numberlist`? What does the 3 in loop return? And how is `A` initialized? Please set up a fuller code block with all needed inputs.

Comment: @T.Ferg to help you properly, we need a minimal dataset to work with. If you can, subset your data, call `dput` on it, then post the result. Good luck!

Comment: @Parfait, here's what's in `numberlist`. I probably should get rid of "$X...no"? However I tried to check if I could use this format by typing `for(i in numberlist){print(i) }`, which seemed fine. I've tried to initialise A with `A<-0`, but not sure that's the right way forward.

`> numberlist`
$X...no
 [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 38 39 40 41 42 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
[41] 60 61 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83

Comment: This is the output from `histlist[grep('^17’,names(histlist))]`, also demonstrates what the data set looks like:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qiSx36GxXgywtlAwaHASfE_xvUXijF2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try `for(i in numberlist$X...no)`. It sounds like numberlist is not a vector, but a structure with column named X...no.

Comment: *The above is not working* ... is never helpful for us. Please describe error or undesired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your attempt, you use invalid R names with non-alphanumeric characters not escaped, `cdm[i]df` and `cdm[i]filtered`. It seems you intend to index from a larger container like a list of objects.

To properly generalize your process for all items in *numberlist*, adjust your `^3` setup. Specifically, build empty lists and in loop iteratively assign by index `[i]`:

```
# INITIALIZE LISTS (SAME LENGTH AS numberlist)
A <- vector(mode="list", length = length(numberlist))
cdm_matrices <- vector(mode="list", length = length(numberlist))
cdm_dfs <- vector(mode="list", length = length(numberlist))
cdm_filtered_dfs  <- vector(mode="list", length = length(numberlist))

# POPULATE LISTS
for (i in numberlist$X) {
  ## extract the list of matrices belonging to the first set
  A[i] <- histlist[grep(paste0('^', i), names(histlist))] 

  ## create a colour distance matrix (cdm)
  cdm_matrices[i] <- colordistance::getColorDistanceMatrix(A[i], method="emd", plotting=FALSE)

  ## convert to data frame to fix row names and remove column names
  cdm_dfs[i] <- setNames(as.data.frame(cdm_matrices[i]), NULL)

  ## return elements in the first row and column 2-5 only (retains row names).
  cdm_filtered_dfs[i] <- cdm_dfs[i][1,2:5]
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you only need the last object, `cdm_filtered_df` returned, use `lapply` where you do not need to use or index lists and all objects are local in scope of function (i.e., never saved in global environment):

```
cdm_build <- function(i) {
  A <- histlist[grep(paste0('^', i), names(histlist))]    
  cdm <- colordistance::getColorDistanceMatrix(A, method="emd", plotting=FALSE)    
  cdm_df <- setNames(as.data.frame(cdm), NULL)    
  cdm_filtered_df <- cdm_df[1,2:5]

  return(cdm_filtered_df)    # REDUNDANT AS LAST LINE IS RETURNED BY DEFAULT
}

# LIST OF FILTERED CDM DATA FRAMES
cdm_filtered_dfs <- lapply(numberlist, cdm_build)
```

---

Finally, with either solution above, should you want to build a singular data frame, run `rbind` in a `do.call()`:

```
cdm_final_df <- do.call(rbind, cdm_filtered_dfs)
```

Comment: thank you!! Your second suggestion worked! (After I had converted 'numberlist' from list to vector by: `numberlist2<-numberlist[[1]]`). As the final output is a list rather than a data frame/matrix, I found this worked best for export; `lapply(cdm_filtered_dfs, function(x) write.table(data.frame(x),'final_output.csv', append=T, col.names=NA, sep=',' ))`. It would be perfect if only the column names [X1,X2,X3,X4] didn't hitch along to repeat themselves with every row, but that's trivial - Excel can reformat for me... :) Again, thanks a lot, I'm so very grateful for your help.

Comment: For reference, I tried your first suggestion, but couldn't get around this error message: 
Error in obj[[x[1]]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
In addition: Warning message:
In A[i] <- histlist[grep(paste0("^", i), names(histlist))] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length.

......And calling `cdm_final_df` returned NULL.

Comment: For first suggestion, did you also convert *numberlist*: `numberlist2<-numberlist[[1]]` and iterate off that vector? For second suggestion, run the final single data frame build with `do.call` then run `write.table` **once** (no `lapply` loop with *append*) which will only write one set of column names.